# Can contributors create a new branch in aws/aws-cdk directly?

Tags: aws-cdk

AWS CDK [contributing](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#getting-started) documentation suggests using Gitpod as development environment. The environment clones the original repository and doesn't seem to allow using a fork (at least I didn't find how to do so). Does it mean that contributors can create and push branches to that repository (naming convention: `<user>/<feature-bug-name>`)?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to open Gitpod environment on a specific branch in fork of aws/aws-cdk repository, perform the implementation and open a pull request